# Assemble list comprehension

Tags: python, list

With:

```
A = [7, 15, 21]
print [i, i+1, i+2 for i in A]
```

I'd like to get `[7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 21, 22, 23]`.

Of course like this it doesn't work, and `[[i, i+1, i+2] for i in A]` gives `[[7, 8, 9], [15, 16, 17], [21, 22, 23]]` which is not what I want.

**What's the pythonic way to do this?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a double loop inside your list comprehension:

```
A = [7, 15, 21]
B = [b for i in A for b in (i, i + 1, i + 2)]
# [7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 21, 22, 23]
```